# multi effect processor and loop station

Tags: guitar-effects, looping, looper-pedals

I just got a Boss ME 80 and I'm wondering if I can, somehow, use that and my Boss RC 30 loop station at the same time. I know the ME 80 has a looper option but it's not as powerful as the RC 30. I try connecting it in different ways but I can get it to work.

Comment: We need more information. Does each item work separately? Have you checked all the leads connecting  them? What is the problem - no sound, noise, non-functioning of an item? It's a straight chain of connections. have you consulted the manuals for optional connect paths?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is run your instrument into the multi fx processor, the multi fx *into* the loop pedal, and the loop pedal into your amp.

Guitar -> ME 80 -> RC 30 -> Amp

If you want to record the 'dry' signal for looping - put the RC 30 before the ME 80 in the chain. Note that the entire loop is filtered through the multi fx at that point; you will not be able to record added effects.

Most pedals use the L output for mono if you aren't using stereo L/R output.

If this doesn't work - test that both units are functioning.

Guitar -> ME 80 -> Amp

Guitar -> RC 30 -> Amp

If both units work individually - be positive your chain input/output is correct. Input is the signal from your instrument, output is the signal going into your amp.

Guitar -> in ME 80; out ME 80 -> in RC 30; out RC 30 -> Amp